# How to create variable names & assign values dynamically in R?

Tags: r, text, stringr

Suppose I have the following vector.

```
library(stringr)
aa <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

I want to create variable names and assign each element of `aa` as the value of newly created variables **dynamically**. That is:

```
mm1  mm2  mm3  mm4
"A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
```

where `mm1`, `mm2`, `mm3`, and `mm4` are variable names created dynamically. Any help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `vector` to a `named` `list` and then use `list2env` to create the objects from the names of the `list` (creating multiple objects in the global env - not recommended)

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(aa), paste0("mm", seq_along(aa))), .GlobalEnv)

mm1
#[1] "A"
mm2
#[1] "B"
mm3
#[1] "C"
mm4
#[1] "D"
```

Comment: Thank you!  But the format I specified above matters in my case.

Comment: @Gadaa aren't you creating new objjects in the global env (from your post)

Comment: @Gadaa If you want to create a named vector, do `setNames(aa, paste0("mm", seq_along(aa)))`